# An algo for finding an arrangement of n integers such that for any two numbers a[i] and a[j] (i < j), their average does not lie between them

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an array of n integers, how can we rearrange the numbers in it efficiently such that for any two numbers a[i] and a[j] (i < j), their average does not lie between the two elements?
Please note that (i + 2) <= j < n where n is the length of the array. Only positive integers are allowed for numbers and averages, i.e. for 1 and 2, the average is 1.5 which we need to ignore. Numbers in the original array are distinct.

Let's take an example - if the given array is arr = [1, 2, 4, 7], this is not a valid arrangement at its current state as the average of arr[0] and arr[3] is 4 which the arr[2], so the average 4 is lying somewhere between 1 and 7. But [1, 2, 7, 4] is a valid arrangement.

I thought over this and this is the solution I could come up with, I couldn’t find a real scope for algorithm optimization. I have come across solutions like partitioning the array recursively based on even/odd index and merging them back but it didn't work for certain inputs.

```
from copy import copy
from collections import defaultdict

def arrange_numbers_no_avg_in_between(arr):

    def permutations_helper(i):
        if i == len(arr) - 1:
            num_index_mapping = defaultdict(list)
            for idx, num in enumerate(arr):
                num_index_mapping[float(num)].append(idx)
                
            for start in range(len(arr) - 2):
                for end in range(start + 2, len(arr)):
                    avg = (float(arr[start]) + float(arr[end])) / 2
                    if any(start < idx < end for idx in num_index_mapping[avg]):
                        return
            return copy(arr)
        else:
            for j in range(i, len(arr)):
                arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
                result = permutations_helper(i + 1)
                if result:
                    return  result
                arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
                
    return permutations_helper(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print arrange_numbers_no_avg_in_between([1, 4, 2, 7])
    print arrange_numbers_no_avg_in_between([1, 201, 202, 431, 522])
    print arrange_numbers_no_avg_in_between(list(range(10)))
```

And here is the output I received,

```
[1, 2, 7, 4]
[1, 201, 202, 431, 522]
[0, 8, 4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 3, 9, 7]
```

The time complexity for my algorithm seems to be O(n.n!), I would appreciate any help for a better and efficient algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: Are the integers distinct?

Comment: So as the average of 1&2 is 1.5 and it is integers all numbers are allowed between them?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I hope the question is much clearer now.

Comment: Are all the numbers distinct? or are there duplicates?

Comment: If a number `x` repeats 3 times (or more), this is not possible. In any arrangement, one occurrence of `x` will fall between the other two.

Comment: I think O(n log n) is possible: you can always split into even numbers followed by odd numbers (since the average of an even and an odd number can never be in the list), and now you just have to solve the same problem for the even subset and the odd subset. But you can recurse: for the even subset divide each number by two and repeat, and similarly apply the problem recursively to the set of (n - 1)/2 for n in the odd subset. In the end, what this amounts to is sorting by the reverse of the binary representation of each number.

Comment: For example, if your numbers are 0 through 15 (inclusive): `sorted(range(16), key=lambda n: f'{n:04b}'[::-1])` gives `[0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson that is three remarkable insights, even/odd, recurs and reverse binary!

Answer (score 9):

## Short answer

If `arr` is a Python list of nonnegative `int`s, and if there are no triply-repeated values in the array, then

```
sorted(arr, key=lambda n: f'{n:b}'[::-1])
```

is a permutation of `arr` with the desired property. If there *are* triply repeated values, then as [@hilberts_drinking_problem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4585963/) observed in a comment, *no* permutation has the desired property.

### Example

```
>>> arr = list(range(10))
>>> arr
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> sorted(arr, key=lambda n: f'{n:b}'[::-1])
[0, 8, 4, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 7]
```

## Longer answer, and explanation

Let's call a list "shiny" if it has the desired property. (Feel free to replace "shiny" with your favourite adjective throughout. Naming things is hard.)

Then there are a few properties of shininess that are easy to check:

- Any sublist (preserving order) of a shiny list is shiny. For example, `[0, 8, 4, 2, 6, 1,  9, 5, 3, 7]` is shiny, so the sublist `[0, 4, 2, 9, 3]` is shiny.
- If `arr` is shiny and we add or subtract a constant integer `k` to each value in `arr`, the resulting list is still shiny. For example, `[0, 8, 4, 2]` is shiny, so `[1, 9, 5, 3]` is shiny.
- If all elements of `arr` are even, then `arr` is shiny if and only if the array we get by halving each element of `arr` is shiny. For example, from the fact that `[0, 8, 4, 2, 6]` is shiny, we know immediately that `[0, 4, 2, 1, 3]` is shiny, and vice versa.

Now let `arr` be our input list. Then we can find a shiny permutation (if one exists) by:

- dividing the values in `arr` into the even values `arr_even` and the odd values `arr_odd`
- finding a shiny permutation of the even values (more on this shortly)
- finding a shiny permutation of the odd values (ditto)
- putting the two permutations together: evens followed by odds

Now if we pick any two numbers in the resulting array: if they're both even, they both belong to the first (shiny) portion, so their average doesn't lie between them. Similarly if they're both odd. And if one is odd and one is even then the average is not an integer, so it can't be in the list. So the resulting list is shiny.

But how do we find a shiny permutation of the even values? Just halve all  the elements of the array and recurse. Similarly, to find a shiny permutation of the odd values, compute the list of `(n-1)//2` for each `n` in the array and recurse.

The recursion makes progress (either the lists getting shorter, or the values in the lists getting smaller) except in the case where all elements of the list are zero. In that case the array is shiny if it has 2 or fewer elements, and there's no shiny permutation if it has 3 or more elements.

Here's some code, optimised more for clarity than efficiency:

```
def shiny(arr):
    """ Return a shiny permutation of arr, if one exists. """

    # Base case: all zeros
    if not any(arr):
        if len(arr) > 2:
            raise ValueError("No shiny permutation")
        return arr

    # Recurse: divide into evens and odds
    return [
        2 * m for m in shiny([n // 2 for n in arr if n % 2 == 0])
    ] + [
        2 * m + 1 for m in shiny([(n - 1) // 2 for n in arr if n % 2 == 1])
    ]
```

Examples:

```
>>> shiny([1, 2, 4, 7])
[4, 2, 1, 7]
>>> shiny([1, 201, 202, 431, 522])
[522, 202, 1, 201, 431]
>>> shiny(range(10))
[0, 8, 4, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 7]
```

But we can do better: looking at the recursive process, we start by separating based on the least significant bit: the even numbers are those with least significant bit `0`, and then the odd numbers are those with least significant bit `1`. And then since we divide everything by two, the *next* level down of the recursion separates based on the second least significant bit of the original number, and then the next level on the third least significant bit, and so on. In the limit, all we're doing is sorting based on the binary expansion of each integer, but with the least significant bit first.

So the whole algorithm can be expressed as a sort, using as a key the reversed binary expansion:

```
>>> sorted(range(10), key=lambda n:f'{n:b}'[::-1])
[0, 8, 4, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 7]
```